# Several different artifacts in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to have several artifacts with different conditions from my pipeline step.
One artifact (the run log) should be available **on_failure** and one other, the JUnit result available **always**.

How do i configure that?

Comment: You can't create two different artifatcs from one job. You can create new stage after this one. The main test stage can create artifact that include error log and JUnit result. After that on other stage one job can be triggerd on_failure and that job can upload error log artifact, other job can run every time and upload JUnit result to another artifact.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18744

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple paths with different expiry time in gitlab-ci runners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241987/multiple-paths-with-different-expiry-time-in-gitlab-ci-runners)

Comment: Not really. It is close but will not solve the condition problem since the condition is present only on the first step. Thanks though!